# Is it usury or exploitative if the artist charged a trading fee when someone trades his arts?

Tags: fiqh, finance

I am an artist, and I make digital arts.

Is it usury or exploitative if I charge a trading fee everytime someone trades my artwork on a secondary market? because there are market platforms with this kind of feature and I'm wondering if I'm doing a bad thing if I enroll in this type of payment method.

For example,

1. The first trade was me selling my artwork to the first owner. He paid in full. The trading fee of 1% of the cost of the artwork was included in the trading amount.
2. For the second trade and so on, each time an owner sells my artwork to a new buyer, and I charged a 1% trading fee, which means the seller will only receive 99% of what the seller asked for.

Of course, I will let the buyer and seller know about the 1% trading fee and how the money will be used for (to support me, used for the project maintenance itself or to create more new projects, etc.)

This is not royalty fee as trading fee is only paid during the trade while royalty is paid everytime someone uses my artwork.

Is this usury or exploitative?